# Yii Query builder : multi bindValue in for loop caues Fail?

Tags: php, yii

I have a search feature in my CMS, allow user input more than one keyword and search in the pages's title and content.

First, I have make a SQL by concatenation string, then pass into createCommand(), it work.
However I fail to make in into query builder style, and it was fail with message : 
`Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.`

Please make a help to see where I get wrong.

---

This is the working code (pass SQL string) :

```
    $sql  = 'SELECT * ';
    $sql .= 'FROM page';
    $sql .= 'WHERE (';
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {   
        $sql .= 'title LIKE :keyword_'.$i;
        $sql .= ' || ';
        $sql .= 'content LIKE :keyword_'.$i;
        if($i != count($keywords)){
            $sql .= ' || ';
            $i ++;
        }
    }
    $sql .= ');';

    $command =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
        $command->bindValue(':keyword_'.$i, "%$keyword%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $i ++;
    }
    $result = $command->queryAll();
    return $result;
```

This is the fail code (query builder) :

```
    $command =  Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('*')
        ->from('page');
        $i = 1;
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
        $command 
            -> orWhere('title LIKE :keyword_'.$i)
            -> orWhere('content LIKE :keyword_'.$i)
            ->bindValue(':keyword_'.$i, "%$keyword%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $i ++;
    }
    $result = $command->queryAll();
    return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

CDbComman::orWhere() second parameter can be used to bind params

```
foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    $command 
        -> orWhere('title LIKE :keyword_'.$i, array(':keyword_'.$i => "%$keyword%"))
        -> orWhere('content LIKE :keyword_'.$i, array(':keyword_'.$i => "%$keyword%"));
    $i ++;
}
```

EDIT:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#orWhere-detail

Hope it helped